# django - Could I have messed up my setting.py file or is this a problem with my code?

Tags: python, django

My code was working until I created a base.html template for the header and the footer. I undid most of my changes to my project and reran the server but it still shows this error on the webpage:

````
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include('Website.urls')),
]




```Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/
Using the URLconf defined in DIALYSIS.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
Home.html [name='Home']
contact.html [name='contact']
The empty path didn't match any of these.

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
````

The terminal gives this error:

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
June 16, 2020 - 09:22:12
Django version 3.0.7, using settings 'DIALYSIS.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Not Found: /
[16/Jun/2020 09:26:57] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 2267
C:\DialysisCenter\DIALYSIS\DIALYSIS\settings.py changed, reloading.
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
June 16, 2020 - 09:25:29
Django version 3.0.7, using settings 'DIALYSIS.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Not Found: /
[16/Jun/2020 09:29:40] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 2267
Not Found: /
[16/Jun/2020 09:29:41] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 2267
Not Found: /
[16/Jun/2020 09:29:46] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 2267
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
June 16, 2020 - 09:29:39
Django version 3.0.7, using settings 'DIALYSIS.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
(virtual)
```

This is my urls.py code.

```
    from django.contrib import admin
    from django.urls import path, include

    urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path('',include('Website.urls')),
    ]
```

Comment: Could you give some code? and an error code too?

Comment: I'm sorry I am only new to web development but what could the error code be? What i posted was what i am getting when i try to load my project
I am very very sorry

Comment: Are you getting 2 errors? It seems as if you are. Could you also add some more of your code? We can see if there is some error there.

Comment: Is my edit helpful? thats what i get from the terminal

Comment: Could you give some of your code? Maybe I'll understand your problem better.

Comment: I am really sorry but do i get a code from urls.py? or Home.html? or contact.html?

Comment: Sorry, I am no expert in Front-end like Django. I was just asking so other people could understand your problem better. I'll leave it to the professionals :,(

Comment: Okay sir I am still very thankful for your help! :>

Comment: Hi @KhyleCarabio For what I see your problem is due to  a misconfiguration of your URLS can you please add in your post the code of your urls.py placed in your Website site please?

Comment: Will do sir! Thank you very much! I really appreciate it

Comment: This is my urls.py code.

```
    from django.contrib import admin
    from django.urls import path, include

    urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path('',include('Website.urls')),
    ]
```

Comment: @KhyleCarabio Can you share `Website.urls`? Looks like you don't have a path that matches the root of your site (an empty string/path)

Comment: Im sorry sir but i figured it out. my error was in my settings.py
I put a port number in string and it worked? I really did'nt know how its happening but it seems fine because its sending me email